# Remove meta box from posts list screen

Tags: php, wordpress, admin, meta-boxes

Im trying to remove the parent metabox from the posts page(Not the actual post but from page that lists all the posts I have). The metabox show when Im quick editing one of the posts in the list.

I have already tried the following but I suppose this is only for a single post no the list.

```
 remove_meta_box( 'pageparentdiv' , 'post' , 'side' );
 remove_meta_box( 'pageparentdiv' , 'post' , 'normal' );
 remove_meta_box( 'pageparentdiv' , 'post' , 'advanced' );
```

If anyone happens to know how to do this any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Check this, my research leads to the same conclusion : There's no hooks to modify the Quick Edit, it has to be done with CSS and/or jQuery. http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/59871/remove-specific-items-from-quick-edit-menu-of-a-custom-post-type